# can someone help me about these errors

Tags: ios

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAajK.png)

I am getting some errors as shown in the screenshot, can someone help me solve the errors.please let me know if any further information regarding this issue is required shall post them in detail.

Comment: You'll need to supply more information, all I can see there are a lot of missing files.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it can't find the file you're specifying. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but perhaps your target file isn't in the correct directory. Try finding it in the Explorer first then copy and paste the address into the code. Hope this helps!